# function iteration in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm a beginner in Mathematica programming. My code is not running as expected. I wonder if anyone could examine what goes wrong? Here is part of the code.

```
F[{k_, n_, x_}] =
Which[k == 0, f[a, b, x],
k == 1, g[a, b, n, x],
k == 2, h[c, d, n, x]]

G[x_] = F[{0, 0, x}]

While[Extract[G[x], 1] != 3, G[x_] = F[G[x]]]
```

The functions `f`, `g` and `h` are defined by `Which` as is `F`, and they are all vector-valued so that it makes sense to iterate `F`. What I want to achieve is: given initial value `{0,0,x}`, keep iterating `F` until the first component of `F` becomes `3`. Is there anything, e.g. syntax, wrong in the above code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As jVincent mentioned, I would use `:=` instead of `=` while defining F.

I would also use the built in [`NestWhile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NestWhile.html) instead of manually iterating.

```
NestWhile[F, {0, 0, x}, Function[e, Extract[e, 1] != 3]]
```

I can't quite comment on how to correct the code as written because I'm not entirely sure how reassigning `G` in the `While` works.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `SetDelayed` (`:=`) for function definitions like: `F[x_]:=x`. When you use `Set` (`=`) like `F[x_]=x`, the it is essentially the same as `F[_]=x` since the definition isn't delayed until evaluation, so there is no way to transfer the matched pattern on the left hand side into the evaluation of the right hand side.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I had long thought "=" and ":=" were the same thing. I used to define functions by "f[x_]=" and then evaluate "f[1]" and it seems always to give the expected value.